# Is it possible to Export TFS 2010 Build Definitions?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild, definitions

I'm cleaning up old build definitions and I want to back them up in case there is something I'm missing, is there a way to export the build definitions using Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the TFS API to export it to a format that you could load it back in with like in [How to Move TFS 2010 Build Definition between Projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068834/how-to-move-tfs-2010-build-definition-between-projects/5071689#5071689) .

Comment: Dang! Yea, I haven't seen anything out of the box either - I was hoping there was, though. =\

Comment: I had seen this other solution before but was hoping for something out of the box. Ah well now I know.

Answer (score 4):

Team Foundation Power Tools commands has a command that will allow one to export/dump out a build definition to a text file.

From the Visual Studio command prompt:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>**tfpt builddefinition /dump *ProjectName\BuildDefinitionName* /filepath:C:\filename.txt /collection:uri**

Comment: There is another switch for the tfpt builddefinition which I found useful. /diff opened up my compare tool with text representations of the two build definitions that I had specified.  
tfpt builddefinition /diff <Team Project Name>\<Source Build Definition Name> <Team Project Name>\<Target Build Definition Name>