# Is it possible to export all build and release definitions from VSTS in a single go?

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to export ***all*** build and release definitions from VSTS in a single go ?

I know it was possible with TFS,

[Is it possible to Export TFS 2010 Build Definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107824/is-it-possible-to-export-tfs-2010-build-definitions)

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT I really appreciate your time to answer my question, I am in middle of something, as soon as I try and make it work, I will accept the answer, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike TFS you could use tfpt command line.  In Azure DevOps, the simple way is using **Rest API** to do this.

You could use [list build/release definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) first, it should return a json file.

Normally, when you import the JSON file, you will get a new build definition.

Besides, if you are using [YAML builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/build-yaml) which will configure your CI process as code. You could directly copy `.yml` files.

The release definitions are the same as build.

Answer (score 2):

Well, by the same token, you can use Azure Devops API to export those.

[List build definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)
[List release definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

Comment: Some things to probably note about this approach ... exporting the build definitions leverage hard-coded specific id values.  If you try to import later maybe to a fresh environment, you might have issues with things that leverage a specific id (variable groups, tasks groups, etc)